# Input devices stop working when playing Battlefield 4 and Battlefield: Hardline

Tags: keyboard, mouse, freeze

I just downloaded the Battlefield Hardline (BFH) beta only to discover that my mouse and keyboard input freezes every few seconds. It's just the input not the cursor, because in menus the selector freezes but not the cursor.

I figured it was a just a BFH thing but then I opened BF4 (which I'd played through a couple of weeks ago) and it's doing the same thing. My computer's never done this before and I think it's doing it on everything now (however I've only tested BF4 and BFH) but not in windows explorer.

I've tried:

- Updating Nvidia drivers
- Changed USB ports
- Different mouse and keyboard
- Restarted PC (obviously)
- Quit running programs
- Started in diagnostic mode (only starts necessary services)

But nothing makes any difference. I also tried swapping my brothers HDD into my PC (his PC is identical except for GPU) and it worked fine which means it can't be hardware unless it's my HDD itself. Ran chkdsk, no errors.

I want to make it clear that the game doesn't freeze, only the input devices. If I'm moving when it freezes I keep running that direction until it unfreezes.

Comment: Turns out it was just the latest version of Origin being an idiot. Disabled Origin In-Game and the problem went away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was just the latest version of Origin being an idiot. Disabled Origin In-Game and the problem went away.